# Access SharePoint intranet Using Google Chrome and FireFox on Mac machine

Tags: sharepoint, firefox, google-chrome, sharepoint-2010, ntlm

When i try to open our company's SharePoint Portal using Google Chrome or FireFox from Mac machine, log-in popup keeps prompting infinitely, i tried Domain\Username but still asking for user name and password, it works only with Safari but not Chrome nor FF, Please let me know why me and everyone using MAC is not able to access SharePoint Portal.
its is using NTLM authentication with SSL.
Any Idea??

Answer (score 1):

This might not fix it. An additional setting should be changed as well.

network.auth.force-generic-ntlm should be set to true.

network.auth.force-generic-ntlm | user set | boolean | true

Answer (score 0):

this issue is caused by the fact that NTLM is not enabled by default in firefox...

try editing this option: `network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris` from about:config in Firefox

ps. Read [this](http://sivel.net/2007/05/firefox-ntlm-sso/)